Can never "import x.x" from directory "x" containing "x.py"?
I have installed a custom package pg_util using
cd  ~/software/fingerWriterAI/pg_util
pip install -e .

pg_util has the structure:
pg_util/         # repo directory
pg_util/setup.py
pg_util/pg_util #  module directory
pg_util/pg_util/__init__.py # Empty, marks as a module
pg_util/pg_util/pg_util.py  # Main module file
pg_util/tests/ ...


The following import works
(py3) sir@cork:~$ python -c "from pg_util.pg_util import DatabaseParams"

But if I do the same from:
(py3) sir@cork:~$ cd ~/software/fingerWriterAI/pg_util/pg_util
(py3) sir@cork:~/software/fingerWriterAI/pg_util/pg_util$ python -c "from pg_util.pg_util import DatabaseParams"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pg_util.pg_util'; 'pg_util' is not a package
(py3) sir@cork:~/software/fingerWriterAI/pg_util/pg_util$ 

Why can't I from pg_util.pg_util import as an absolute import from within the pg_util/pg_util directory? (I assume its because there's a pg_util.py file, but I didn't ask for from pg_util import or import .pg_util, I asked for from pg_util.pg_util import.
I neither want to choose a custom working directory every time I run a file in my IDE that lives inside a module, nor I want to not have a file that's the same as my module.
Is this issue specific to have having a pg_util file in the same directory as the current folder?
Am I out of luck?

In your example, you don't have a pgutil, just pg_util directories and a pg_util.py file. Python adds current working directory to the front of its path and if you have like named files and directories, the one in CWD is what you are going to get. If you don't want to worry about your CWD when you run, then don't use the same name for modules and files. And don't name .py files after packages you'd expect in your distribution. Your own os.py or sys.py, for example, would have the same problem of masking the one you really want.

Fixed the question (Its all pg_util, no pgutil - my bad).
I guess I'm surprised because I ask for a full qualified name: from pg_util.pg_util import ...  not from pg_util import ... and it can know I'm asking for the package pg_util not the module.  from A.B import ..., A is always a package right?

No. Reading through The import statement, the from form will find the module specified in the from clause, loading and initializing it if necessary;. The "module" could be a .py file or a directory. It could even be some third thing, like an entry in a .zip file because pythons supports multiple module loaders.

In any case, it goes into the sys.modules cache, which is a dict. That's one of the reasons why python doesn't try to guess things based on multiple . in an import statement. You can't have two modules or packages with the same name at the root level because the sys.modules dict can't have multiple identical keys.
